# python3 try-catch def function

Tags: python-3.x, function, math, try-catch, nonetype

Imagine you're writing the software that controls the speed
#of a ceiling fan. The user changes the fan's speed by
#pulling a string. Pulling the string increases the fan's =
#speed by 1, unless it's already at the maximum speed. If
#it's already at the maximum speed, it changes the speed
#back to 0.
#
#Write a function called pullString. pullString should take
#two parameters: a current speed, and a maximum speed, both
#integers. pullString should return the new fan speed
#according to the reasoning above.

```
 #You may assume that the input will be integers. You should
#also assume that the fan's speed *can* equal the maximum
#speed, but it *cannot* exceed the maximum speed. You may
#thus assume that you will never be given a currentSpeed
#higher than maxSpeed.


#Write your function here!
   

#to fix this problem here are my answer:

    def pullString(current_speed,maximum_speed):
        try:
            if maximum_speed > current_speed:
                fan_speed = current_speed+1
                return fan_speed
        except:
            if maximum_speed <= current_speed:
                fan_speed = current_speed-current_speed
                return fan_speed
    
    
    
    print(pullString(2, 5))
    print(pullString(4, 5))
    print(pullString(7, 7))


#The code below will test your function. It isn't used for
#grading, so you can change or remove it if you'd like. As
#written, these three lines should print 3, 5, and 0.


#the output was 3 and 5 and none #my problem with word None .it should print 3 5 0 not none
```

Comment: Why do you need to use try except then? It just need if and else?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it output `None` is when `current_speed=7` and `maximum_speed=7`, the try block run, and the `if maximum_speed > current_speed` is false. This lead to return nothing (not run the expect block) so the output will be `None`

One of the solution you can think of is first increase the current speed, and if it exceed maximum one, assign 0 to it.

```
def pullString(current_speed,maximum_speed):
    current_speed += 1
    if (current_speed==maximum_speed+1):
        current_speed = 0
    return current_speed

print(pullString(2, 5))
print(pullString(4, 5))
print(pullString(7, 7))
```

Another solution which is shorter is that using modulo:

```
def pullString(current_speed,maximum_speed):
    return (current_speed+1)%(maximum_speed+1)
print(pullString(2, 5))
print(pullString(4, 5))
print(pullString(7, 7))
```

Comment: thank you for the respond i was going at it in different approach without changing the approach i was stuck with it for time ;)